# Insert multiple ENUM values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, enums

Is it possible insert more than one `ENUM` value in a column in postgres?

e.g. In Mysql, I can do.

```
create table 'foo'(
    'foo_id' smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `foo_enum` enum('foo','bar','dummy') DEFAULT 'foo',
);

insert into 'foo' ('foo_id', 'foo_enum') values (1, 'foo, bar')
```

Comment: Your syntax is totally wrong. An identifier (column name, table name) neither needs `'` nor that stupid backtick from MySQL. `'foo'` is *not* a table name. It's string literal (even with MySQL).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`CREATE TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-enum.html) to declare your enum:

```
CREATE TYPE tfoo AS ENUM('foo','bar','dummy');
```

And use an [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html) of it to store the values:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (foo_id serial, foo_enum tfoo[]);
```

To insert:

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo_enum) VALUES('{foo,bar}');
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo_enum) VALUES(ARRAY['foo','bar']::tfoo[]);
```

Another approach would be using another table to store the enums and a foreign key to the foo table. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (foo_id serial primary key);
CREATE TABLE foo_enums (foo_id integer references foo(foo_id), value tfoo);
```

And them insert the multiple values into `foo_enums`:

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo_id) VALUES(nextval('foo_id_seq'));
INSERT INTO foo_enums(foo_id, value) VALUES
    (currval('foo_id_seq'), 'foo'),
    (currval('foo_id_seq'), 'bar');
```